# Extend SchemaDirectiveVisitor To Use Apollo Server Schema Directives in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, graphql, directive, apollo-server, hapi

I'm trying to extend SchemaDirectiveVisitor in order to make a custom directive in Apollo Server 2. I'm specifically using the 2.2.6 hapi node module.

Here's my server.js code:

```
const { ApolloServer } = require('apollo-server-hapi');
const { SchemaDirectiveVisitor } = ApolloServer;

class ViewTemplateGroup extends SchemaDirectiveVisitor {
  visitFieldDefinition(field) {
    console.log('Im calling this directive!');
    return;
  }
}
```

When I start up my server I immediately get the following error:

```
TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/garrett.kim/Desktop/Projects/Test Web/poc-graphQL-forms-gyk/server.js:36:33)
    at Module._compile (module.js:660:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:671:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:573:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:513:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:505:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:701:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:193:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:617:3
```

To my knowledge, I'm following the Apollo Server 2 example very closely.

https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/features/creating-directives.html

Any help getting directives working would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The `ApolloServer` class does not have a `SchemaDirectiveVisitor` property on it; therefore, calling `ApolloServer.SchemaDirectiveVisitor` results in undefined and a class cannot extend undefined as the error indicates. Just import `SchemaDirectiveVisitor` directly from the `apollo-server-hapi` module:

```
const { ApolloServer, SchemaDirectiveVisitor } = require('apollo-server-hapi')
```